# CircleCI, how to use container built in previous job?

Tags: circleci

I have this simple config:

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: |
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml build

  test:
    machine: true
    working_directory: ~/app
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          command: make test
          name: Test

workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

My `test` job, the second one, fails for some reasons. But whenever I check the logs on CircleCI, I can see that the image is always built in this job. I was expecting that the job would use the container that was built in the `build` job. So question is, why are containers not shared across jobs?

Comment: Each job runs on a different containers, but you can share the data between the jobs using     - persist_to_workspace:

Comment: from the docs: "Special step used to persist a temporary file to be used by another job in the workflow.".
So I guess it doesn't persist containers